# Probability of $\alpha\log n$ consecutive successes in a Bernoulli process for $\alpha$ small

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{X_{n}\}$ be a sequence off iid random variables with $P(X_{i}=0)=P(X_{i}=1)=1/2.$  For $\alpha>0$, and the event $A_{n}$ whereby in the sequence $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ there are at least $\alpha\log n$ consecutive 1's occuring, show that $P(A_{n}\;i.o.)=1$ for sufficiently small $\alpha>0$.

Any help on getting started here would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $n$ finite? Does $i.o.$  mean "infinitely often"?

Comment: It is finite when defining the $A_{n}$, and yes about the i.o.

Comment: I think the wording might be better.  So apparently you have an infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s, and you want to see how often there are at least $\alpha \log n$ consecutive $1$s in the first $n$ terms, counting over all positive integer $n$.  I expect you will be able to do this by showing $\sum_n P(A_n) = + \infty$ or $E \left[ \sum_n \mathbb{1}_{A_n} \right] = + \infty$

Comment: @Henry note that $A_n$ are not independent but one idea is to show there are large probabilities of large strings of 1 between the $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$ flips

Comment: @Deven Ware: I expect you are right.